# XenServer Networkconfigruation broken after update from 7.5 to 7.6

Tags: networking, xenserver

After an upgrad from xenserver 7.5 to 7.6 through the official XenCenter we discovered, that our network configuration is broken.
We can provide the following details:

XenConsole:

- network card (Broadcom Nextreme, HP DL380 G6) is detected
- NICs are shown as `OK`
- NICs are shown as `NOT CONNECTED`
- Management interface has static IP configured
- cables are connected and blinking
- ping to 127.0.0.1 and to NIC IP works
- ping to gateway or other device in the network fails

Already tried:

- emergency network reset
- adding an removing a second PCIe Network card (Intel 1000 pro)
- changing cables on ports
- change of management interface
- several reboots

If we can provide more information just comment what you need and we will try to add it to the questions asap.

Edit: Refering to the comment. The Network card is on the hcl for 7.6 (http://hcl.xenserver.org/networkadapters/28/Broadcom_Corporation_NetXtreme_II_BCM5709_Gigabit_Ethernet)

Edit2: According to the output of `/sbin/ifconfig` after trying to ping:

- `eth1` rx dropped packages: 0
- `eth1` tx: 0
- `xenbr1` rx: 0
- `xenbr1` tx: 2000+ and increasing

So it looks like the bonding of the pyhsical and managment interface is broken.

Comment: Which network card is it exactly? Is it on the [HCL for 7.6](http://hcl.xenserver.org)? Not every hardware is supported on every version.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider We took a look and yes the network is on the list. We updated the question to reflect the new information.